# The first day of a given date in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

to get the first day of a given month , i have used **strtotime** like above  but it does'nt work i write :

```
   $d = date_parse_from_format("d-m-Y", $date);
   $month= $d["month"];
   $year=$d["year"];
   echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime('FIRST DAY OF $month $year'));
```

Comment: The first day is always `1` ???? What exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: strtotime(date('01/m/Y')

Answer (score 1):

The first day of this month can be expressed as

```
echo date('Y-m-01');
```

You can then extract further information from this if you require, for example the day of the week:

```
$month = '10';
$year  = '2012';
echo date('D', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
```

Comment: i don't want the current date, i want the first day of a given date

Comment: "the first day of a given date" - a date only has one day. Do you mean the first day of a given month?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works:

```
echo date("j", strtotime('FIRST DAY OF $month $year'));
```